# Tailwind CSS Grid Spacing Messed Up

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-grid, tailwind-css

I am trying to make a blog website with two columns for the posts. The first column displays one large-format post while the second displays 3 small-format posts (pictured below). However, when i do this to small-format posts seem to respect the spacing of the large-format post, even though they are in different columns. Here is a picture:

[image]

As you can see, I want the posts on the right side to be spaced evenly, but the second post starts at the end of the large-format post on the first column.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import client from '../client'
import BlockContent from '@sanity/block-content-to-react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

function Main() {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        client.fetch(
            `*[_type == "post"] {
                title,
                slug,
                body,
                author,
                mainImage {
                    asset -> {
                        _id,
                        url
                    },
                    alt
                },
                publishedAt
            }`
        ).then((data) => setPosts(data))
         .catch(console.error)
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className='grid lg:grid-cols-3 md:grid-cols-2 gap-8 m-4 '>
            {posts.slice(0, 1).map((p, i) => (
                <Link to = {`/blog/${p.slug.current}`} className=''>
                    <article key = {p.slug.current} className=''>
                        <img src = {p.mainImage.asset.url} alt = {p.title} className='' />
                        <div>
                            <p className='font-bold text-xl text-secondary'>{p.title}</p>
                            <p className='text-sm'>By Brandon Pyle | {new Date(p.publishedAt).toLocaleDateString()}</p>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </Link>
            ))}
            {posts.slice(1, 4).map((p, i) => (
                <Link to = {`/blog/${p.slug.current}`} className='col-start-2 h-16'>
                    <article key = {p.slug.current} className='flex'>
                        <img src = {p.mainImage.asset.url} alt = {p.title} className='w-auto h-auto max-h-[80px]' />
                        <div>
                            <p className='font-bold text-xl text-secondary'>{p.title}</p>
                            <p className='text-sm'>By Brandon Pyle | {new Date(p.publishedAt).toLocaleDateString()}</p>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </Link>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Main
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas on how to fix this issue! Thanks.

Comment: Hey there, sounds like you're having an issue with your HTML structure and CSS, not your React code. You would be more likely to get help if you were to make a Minimum Reproducible Example using the rendered HTML (you can find it in your browser's dev tools) you can even plug it into https://play.tailwindcss.com and share the playground here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was causing the issue. All I had to do was wrap each of the map functions in a div, like so:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import client from '../client'
import BlockContent from '@sanity/block-content-to-react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

function Main() {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        client.fetch(
            `*[_type == "post"] {
                title,
                slug,
                body,
                author,
                mainImage {
                    asset -> {
                        _id,
                        url
                    },
                    alt
                },
                publishedAt
            }`
        ).then((data) => setPosts(data))
         .catch(console.error)
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className='grid lg:grid-cols-3 md:grid-cols-2 gap-8 m-4 '>
            <div>
                {posts.slice(0, 1).map((p, i) => (
                    <Link to = {`/blog/${p.slug.current}`} className=''>
                        <article key = {p.slug.current} className=''>
                            <img src = {p.mainImage.asset.url} alt = {p.title} className='' />
                            <div>
                                <p className='font-bold text-xl text-secondary'>{p.title}</p>
                                <p className='text-sm'>By Brandon Pyle | {new Date(p.publishedAt).toLocaleDateString()}</p>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    </Link>
                ))}
            </div>

            <div className='my-[-16px]'>
                {posts.slice(1, 4).map((p, i) => (
                    <Link to = {`/blog/${p.slug.current}`} className='col-start-2'>
                        <article key = {p.slug.current} className='flex my-4'>
                            <img src = {p.mainImage.asset.url} alt = {p.title} className='w-auto h-auto max-h-[80px]' />
                            <div>
                                <p className='font-bold text-xl text-secondary'>{p.title}</p>
                                <p className='text-sm'>By Brandon Pyle | {new Date(p.publishedAt).toLocaleDateString()}</p>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    </Link>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Main
```

Answer (score 0):

try build your cols with this code with the size you want to
grid-cols-[80px_400px_1fr_250px]=grid-cols-[first_second_therd]
and check this too [Try build layout with tailwind CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70630174/try-build-layout-with-tailwind-css/70633252#70633252)