# Try build layout with tailwind CSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

i trying to build this layout with tailwind css but i can't figure out

[layout i want to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOrZW.jpg)

[my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gCwv.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/output.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body
    class="font-Rubik grid grid-cols-[80px_minmax(400px,_1fr)_250px] grid-rows-2 h-screen"
  >
    <nav class="bg-slate-800 row-span-2">nav</nav>
    <menu class="bg bg-violet-700 col-span-2 text-white">Menu</menu>
    <section class="bg-slate-300">Inbox</section>
    <main class="bg-slate-300">Email view</main>
    <aside class="bg-slate-300">Additional info</aside>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this, you can mix the grid and flex systems. For the grid you can adjust the individual column widths in the config. i have taken 25/50/25.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/WqVvubeWsT

Answer (score 0):

yo can do it this way to

```
grid-cols-[80px_400px_1fr_250px]
```

just  need add (_) between ich size